# Find most profitable brand by year as a measure of gross profit

Tags: sql, sql-server

Desired output:

| Year | brand | gross_profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | x | 1000 |
| 2016 | y | 2000 |
| 2017 | y | 1500 |
| 2018 | x | 2000 |

However, with the following code, I am yielding highest profit per *brand* per year. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
--Find most profitable brand for each year (measured by gross profit)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Year, 
    brand,
    MAX(gross_profit) AS gross_profit
FROM dbo.Data$
GROUP BY brand, Year
ORDER BY YEAR ASC;
```

Comment: You need to show some sample data to go with your desired results.

Comment: `with data as (select "year", brand, dense_rank() over (partition by "year" order by gross_profit desc) as dr from dbo.Data$) select * from data where dr = 1 order by "year", brand;`

Answer (score 0):

We can use a sub-query to find the highest gross-profit each year.

> ```
> create table data(
> Year int,
> brand varchar(10),
> gross_profit int);
> insert into data values
> (2015,'x',1000),
> (2016,'y',2000),
> (2017,'y',1500),
> (2018,'x',2000),
> (2015,'y',800),
> (2016,'x',1750),
> (2017,'x',1000),
> (2018,'y',1500);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     d.Year, 
>     d.brand,
>     d.gross_profit
> FROM Data d
> JOIN ( SELECT Year y,
>        MAX(gross_profit) mgp
>        FROM Data
>        GROUP BY Year) ym
> ON Year = y 
>   AND gross_profit = mgp
> ORDER BY YEAR ASC;
> ```
>
> ```
> Year | brand | gross_profit
> ---: | :---- | -----------:
> 2015 | x     |         1000
> 2016 | y     |         2000
> 2017 | y     |         1500
> 2018 | x     |         2000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=fda99a952605e75652417b3eaffcd55c)*